# Sub select vs declared variable in where

Tags: sql, sql-server

A question on where clauses. which is more efficient?

```
    Select * from tbl t where t.date > (select convert(date,'2013-08-21'))
```

Or

```
     Declare @dt as date
     Set @dt = (select convert(date,'2013-08-21')))
     Select * from tbl t where t.date > @dt
```

thanks

Comment: Why dont you just do `Select * from tbl t where t.date > '2013-08-21'`

Comment: sorry I throught that would be comparing a varchar to a date and the conversion was required beforehand?

Comment: it depends also on the RDBMS... assuming SQL Server, I have always used `'date'`

Comment: Your first query is close, you just need to switch the convert to the column value to work the way you're intending: `Select * from tbl t where CONVERT(date, t.date) > '2013-08-21'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to declare a variable or do a nested select:

```
Select * from tbl t where t.date > '2013-08-21'
```

That should work for you!

Comment: This is correct, however keep in mind that if your `t.date` value is a datetime type, then using `> '2013-08-21'` will include any values over `'2013-08-21 00:00:00.000'` so a value at 8am that day would be included. If you want to exclude that day, then either convert `t.date` to a short date format or move to the next day.